# Is any set a proper subset of the null set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there any $X$, such that $X \subset \emptyset = T$?

I suppose this is related to asking whether [$\emptyset \subset \emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265675/is-empty-set-a-proper-subset-of-itself), but not exactly the same.

Comment: Can a set have less than no elements?

Comment: There would have to be a point in $\varnothing$ that is not in $\varnothing$. This is a contradictory pair of conditions, so -- no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A \subset B$ means two things are true:

- if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$
- there exists $x \in B$ such that $x \notin A$

Now if there is some set $X$ such that $X \subset \emptyset$, it must be the case that

- if $x \in X$, then $x \in \emptyset$
- there exists $x \in \emptyset$ such that $x \notin X$

The second bullet point cannot ever hold because there cannot exist $x \in \emptyset$. So there cannot be such a set $X$.

Answer (score 2):

To have 
$$X\subset\emptyset$$
we need that every element in $X$ is also in $\emptyset$ and that there exists an element in $\emptyset$ that is not in $X$. As $\emptyset$ contains no elements, the second condition cannot hold, and hence the statement is not true.